# SQL Query error when displaying article list

Tags: articles

I am running a number of sites on the same server. All are updated to Joomla 3.8.2
Suddenly some of them but not all have the following problem.

When I list the articles I get a list of the first 20 articles.
URL: http://DOMAIN/administrator/index.php?option=com_content

After clicking the next button I get an error 500:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 9
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY a.id desc LIMIT 20' at line 11
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 9

From here I can only go back to the control panel.
From now on the article list immediately gives the error 500

After logging out and in I get the list of the first 20 items again.
What could be wrong here and how do I solve this?

Comment: Did you find a resolution for this issue?  If it still persists, can you offer more details about the sql query? Can we see the `->dump()`'ed query?  Are we dealing with multi-byte characters? Database version/settings? If you have any additional details, they may be helpful in resolving this page.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of 2 things:

- A plugin that is causing this mess
- A core modification that was implemented to optimize the article loading process but is incompatible with Joomla 3.8.2

First, try disabling system/content plugins one by one until the problem is resolved. If it is not, then try "refreshing" the Joomla core files by copying over a fresh copy of Joomla onto your site (make sure you backup your website first, and make sure you remove the `installation` folder before copying the files over).

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention that directly.
I already refreshed the Joomla core files and also disabled all system and even all website plugins.
The problem still exists.